# Using OpenID Connect OWIN module as an identity provider in IdentityServer3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identityserver3

I am running IdentityServer3 in an asp.net v5 environment. I am attempting to hookup the OWIN OpenID Connect module as an identity provider, so that users can login through IDS3 using either local credentials or credentials federated out of an Azure AD instance. Here's my setup:

**Identity provider configuration:**

```
 public static void ConfigureIdentityProviders(IAppBuilder app, string signInAsType)
        {         
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = "a-valid-client-id",
                    Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/some-valid-authority",
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:44300/",
                    SignInAsAuthenticationType = OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                    CallbackPath = new PathString("/identity/callback"),
                    ResponseType = "code id_token token"
                });
        }
```

**IDS3 Configuration:**

```
  app.Map("/identity", idsrvApp =>
            {                
                idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions()
                {
                    SiteName = "Identity Server",
                    SigningCertificate = LoadCertificate(),
                    AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions()
                    {
                        IdentityProviders = ConfigureIdentityProviders
                    },

                    Factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
                        .UseInMemoryUsers(Users.Get())
                        .UseInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
                        .UseInMemoryScopes(StandardScopes.All)
                });            
            });
```

This part works fine, and Azure returns a token to the nominated endpoint as a POST request. I receive the following error:

```
{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."}
```

I've tried all sorts of different redirect URLs - e.g., redirecting to "/", redirecting to some other page within "/identity", and always get the same error. I am not sure if there should be some resource I mount at a postback URL that handles the token explicitly, but I was under the impression that OWIN should be handling this for me?

I am starting to think it may be a problem that I've caused by using OWIN middleware with ASP.net 5.

Thanks!

Comment: Can I suggest you take a look at [ASOS](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server). I'm using it currently and am having a good experience with it. There are samples available to get you up and running.

Comment: If you only have one oidc ext provider - you don't need to set the callback path - maybe try without setting it to remove one possible source of errors

Comment: Good tip - turned it off and progressed further. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the redirect URI Azure AD was returning the token to was not the same as the one configured on the OID Connection. When this mismatch happens, nothing listens for POST on the return URL and you get the error above.

After this, the next problem I received was something to the effect of "Error identifying calling application", popping up in IDS3 on the token return endpoint. This was solved by adding the following configuration to the OID Connect object:

```
TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        AuthenticationType = IdentityServer3.Core.Constants.ExternalAuthenticationType
                    }
```